# Java inheritance compilation

Tags: java, eclipse, inheritance, compilation

I cannont compile a simple Java project with one class inheritance.

Without the inheret class the project compiles well, when I add the class I get the message in Eclipse: "Errors exist in required project". What is strange is that if I click "Proceed" the project runs fine, but yet there is a message for an error after compilation. What should I do not to have this error?

Here is the code, I have a main class but for now I do not do anything in it.

```
    public class Person
{
    private String name;
    private int health;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();  
    public Person(String name,int x,int y)
    {
        this.nom = name;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        health = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
    }
    public void Attack(int damage)
    {
        healh+=damage;
    }
    public int getHealth()
    {
        return health; 
    }
}
//Without the class Warrior, I do not get error message
public class Warrior extends Person
{
    protected int damage;
    public void faireAttaque(Person p)
    {
        p.Attack(damage);
    }
}
//When I added the Warrior class, I got the error message
```

Comment: Do you have both classes in the same file? Usually, `public` classes are separated to their own files.

Comment: Both classes are in the same project, is that what you mean?

Comment: I meant you could try to put `Person` into `Person.java` and `Warrior` into `Warrior.java`. It's just a guess because Android Studio always complains about that.

Comment: You're not reading at the right error message, it could have helped you. I think mtyurt gave you the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your child class should implement a constructor and call `super`.

```
public class Warrior extends Person {
    public Warrior(String name, int x, int y)
    {
        super(name,x,y);
    }
    //other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are missing the constructor in your Warrior class. You need it because you inherit non default constructor of Person class. Secondly, you need to separate these classes into two files.